# Multiple, repeating modifier keys in Karabiner

Tags: macos, keyboard, karabiner

I am in the process of setting up Karabiner to replace ControllerMate for an N52 Nostromo controller, which now shows up as the left-hand portion of a standard keyboard.
I have a number of complex modification rules, all of which are using "frontmost_application_if", and "device_if" to limit scope. I have two rules that work on their own, but do not work when pressed together:

```
"from": { "key_code": "r" },"to": [ {"key_code": "left_shift", "repeat": true } ]
```

```
"from": { "key_code": "spacebar" }, "to": [ {"key_code": "left_alt" } ]
```

With 'R' held, I get 'shift', but once I also press 'spacebar', instead of getting 'alt', I get 'shift' and 'spacebar'
I also tried setting a variable with the shift rule, and had a second 'alt-shift' rule that triggers on 'spacebar' + the variable, but it won't fire, and it seems like it has something do to with a modifier being held on repeat.

Can these be combined?

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to write "repeat": true.
"repeat" is true *by default* and only can be changed to false (for 1 key / the last in a sequence).

Second, your two lines work together* if you append the "lazy" modifier as in:

```
"from": { "key_code": "r" },"to": [ {"key_code": "left_shift", "lazy": true } ]
```

Karabiner's [documentation on "lazy"](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/to/lazy/) states:
***The lazy modifier does not send own key events until another key is pressed together.***

… which means that K.'s EventViewer will not display "r" or "left_shift" but only "left_alt".

(* They *may* have to be in the same "manipulators" but still work independently.)

Comment: thanks Clemsam - 
Just to close the loop here, and following the exchange on github: 
Lazy wasn't what I wanted, because "r"==>"Shift" and "space"==>"alt" need to work on their own.
What ended up working was putting `"modifiers":{"optional":["shift"]}` on the space->alt rule and `"modifiers":{"optional":["option"]}` on the other rule.